# Has Microsoft's Internet Explorer anything to do with an ongoing download in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: windows-8, firefox, browser, internet-explorer

I am using Windows 8 on my ASUS laptop. Today, I was downloading a .zip file from Mediafire.com in the Firefox browser when suddenly my Firefox started to lag and stopped responding for about a minute. I opened Task Manager and, to my surprise, I found Internet Explorer using much more CPU than Firefox itself. First, I decided to wait a bit, but I soon lost patience and stopped IE, but it kept on opening by itself, and also kept on consuming high CPU.

[image: The screen shot of the problem.]

As you all can see in the taskbar (of the above screenshot) that IE was not even opened, it was running as a background task. Moreover, I have marked on the picture how IE was consuming much more CPU than Firefox (though memory consumption of Firefox was more but IE was really disturbing me). Also, you can see the progress of the ongoing download beside the search bar in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has no relation to Internet Explorer whatsoever, and even when you install the IETab plug-in for Firefox, an Internet Explorer process **will not** launch.

What you have seen is a simple coincidence. [Correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation).

> I soon lost patience and stopped IE, but it kept on opening by itself, and also kept on consuming high CPU.

Internet Explorer uses a multi-process architecture: A parent Internet Explorer process launches one or more child Internet Explorer processes. If one of the children crashes or is forcibly ended, the parent process launches it again. (**If you look carefully at your screenshot, you'll see two Internet Explorer processes there.**) As such, you must kill the parent process from the "Details" tab with an "End process tree" command. Unfortunately, there is no way to see the parent in Task Manager. You must use either [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) or [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) to see the process hierarchy. Then, kill the parent `iexplore.exe` and all its children at the same time.

[image: Internet Explorer's process hierarchy]

See the process hierarchy has other benefits too: You can see which app has opened IE in the first place. ...and you can kill that app.

**Bonus trick:** Instead of killing the IE process, you could try pausing it too!

> As you all can see in the taskbar (of the above screenshot) that IE was not even opened.

Did you forget that you are on Windows 8? Taskbar on Windows 8 only shows the windows of traditional desktop apps. (This is fixed in Windows 8.1) You must have checked the task switcher for Metro-style apps too. Press and hold <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Sorry for responding late. Btw the answer was great and it helped a lot. As u said in the end that whether I forgot that I was in windows 8- I would say that i had that fact well in my mind. I have stopped the IE to be opened in "Windows-8-app-mode" and  preferred it to be opened it in normal desktop mode(though I should have mentioned it in the first place :P).